# Laravel backpack dependent textbox

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I am stuck with Laravel backpack.

I want to display textboxes when a checkbox  is clicked. i want to implement this in my project. How to implement this using controller?
My fields are initialized in the controller

controller.php

```
  // *****
        // FIELDS ALTERNATIVE
        // *****
        "fields" => [

            [
                'name' => "event_name",
                'label' => "Event name",
                'type' => "text",
                'placeholder' => "First Name and Last Name",
            ],
            [
                'name' => "event_topic",
                'label' => "Event Topic",
                'type' => "text",
                'placeholder' => "Event Topic",
            ],
            [
                'name' => "event_type_id",
                'label' => "Event Type",
                'model' => "App\Larapen\Models\EventType",
                'entity' => "eventType",
                'attribute' => "name",
                'type' => "select",
            ],

           [   // Checkbox
            'name' => 'social_links',
            'label' => 'Links to facebook and twitter',
            'type' => 'checkbox'
        ],
    ]
```

When i click the "social_links" checkbox two textboxes should be displayed in my add page.

Please help me with this.Waiting for a response...........

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var checked = document.getElementById('checkbox');
checked.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked){
   document.getElementById('text_1').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('text_2').style.display='block';
  } else {
   document.getElementById('text_1').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('text_2').style.display='none';
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" aria-label="...">

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="text_1" style="display:none">
Text Area 1 
</textarea>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="text_2" style="display:none">
Text Area 2 
</textarea>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

You need to add some attributes to the fields:

```
$this->crud->addFields([
        [
            'name' => "event_name",
            'label' => "Event name",
            'type' => "text",
            'placeholder' => "First Name and Last Name",
            'attributes' => ['id'=>'text_1', 'style' => 'display:none'],
        ],
        [
            'name' => "event_topic",
            'label' => "Event Topic",
            'type' => "text",
            'placeholder' => "Event Topic",
            'attributes' => ['id'=>'text_2', 'style' => 'display:none'],
        ],
        [   // Checkbox
            'name' => 'social_links',
            'label' => 'Links to facebook and twitter',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'attributes' => ['id'=>'checkbox'],
        ],
]);
```

Comment: when i add attributes in my fields it shows error " ErrorException in helpers.php line 531:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\wamp\www\Classified\resources\views\vendor\backpack\crud\fields\text.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\Classified\resources\views\vendor\backpack\crud\fields\text.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\Classified\resources\views\vendor\backpack\crud\fields\text.blade.php) "

Comment: Probably there was an error in the way  you declared the fields. I updated the code with the full backpack crud syntax

Answer (score 0):

i just made a slight change to the answer provided by Marco.

```
           [   
                'name' => 'social_links',
                'label' => 'Links to facebook and twitter',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'id'=>'checkbox'
            ],
            [
                'name' => "event_name",
                'label' => "Event name",
                'type' => "text",
                'placeholder' => "First Name and Last Name",
                'id'=>'text_1',
            ],
            [
                'name' => "event_topic",
                'label' => "Event Topic",
                'type' => "text",
                'placeholder' => "Event Topic",
                'id'=>'text_2'
            ],
```

in view page

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#text_1').parent().hide();
    $('#text_2').parent().hide();

});

var checked = document.getElementById('checkbox');
checked.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked){
    $('#text_1').parent().show();
    $('#text_2').parent().show();
  } else {
    $('#text_1').parent().hide();
    $('#text_2').parent().hide();
  }
});
</script>
```